# Nightwatch tests fail when running in docker using selenium/chromedriver

Tags: selenium, vue.js, docker-compose, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I am running my whole system using docker-compose and I am trying to execute my end-to-end tests (written with Nightwatch) using a selenium/chrome service that is in the same network. My frontend is VueJS and the image is built from a node base image. I am running the tests with **docker-compose exec frontend npm run test-selenium** and getting the following output:

```
> frontend@0.1.0 test-selenium
> nightwatch -c nightwatch-selenium.conf.js


[Login Test] Test Suite
──────────────────────────────────────────────
ℹ Connected to chrome on port 4444 (1494ms).
  Using: chrome (102.0.5005.61) on LINUX.   


  Running login:
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  ℹ Loaded url http://frontend:8090/login in 2049ms
  NoSuchElementError: An error occurred while running .click() command on <Element [name=@loginBt]>: Timed out while waiting for element "#loginBt" with "css selector" to be present for 5000 milliseconds.
       at Object.login (/app/tests/loginTest.js:8:8)
  NoSuchElementError: An error occurred while running .setValue() command on <Element [name=@emailField]>: Timed out while waiting for element "input[name = "email"]" with "css selector" to be present for 5000 milliseconds.
       at Page.fillUpData (/app/tests/page-objects/loginPage.js:13:21)
       at Object.login (/app/tests/loginTest.js:9:8)
  NoSuchElementError: An error occurred while running .setValue() command on <Element [name=@passField]>: Timed out while waiting for element "input[name = "password"]" 
with "css selector" to be present for 5000 milliseconds.
       at Page.fillUpData (/app/tests/page-objects/loginPage.js:13:21)
       at Object.login (/app/tests/loginTest.js:10:8)
  NoSuchElementError: An error occurred while running .click() command on <Element [name=@submitBt]>: Timed out while waiting for element "button[name = "submit"]" with 
"css selector" to be present for 5000 milliseconds.
       at Object.login (/app/tests/loginTest.js:11:8)
  ✖ Testing if the URL contains '/cards' in 5000ms - expected "contains '/cards'" but got: "http://frontend:8090/login" (5143ms)
    at Object.login (/app/tests/loginTest.js:12:15)


FAILED: 1 assertions failed and  4 errors (28.22s)
```

When running tests locally, everything is working just fine. For local tests, I am using the chrome driver installed as dev dependency, accessing the frontend using **http://localhost:8090/**.

It is my first time dealing with E2E tests in docker, so I am not really sure what is going wrong. Any help is appreciated. Please find the source code below. Let me know if I need to add any more information.

- **package.json**

```json
"scripts": {
   ...
    "test": "nightwatch",
    "test-selenium": "nightwatch -c nightwatch-selenium.conf.js",
   ...
  },
```

- **docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: card-market-frontend/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: npm run serve
    working_dir: /app
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"

  chrome:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
    hostname: chrome
    privileged: true
    shm_size: 2g
```

- When running the tests with the **test-selenium** command I am using the nightwatch.conf below:

```js
const chromedriver = require("chromedriver");

require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = {
  src_folders: ["/tests"],
  page_objects_path: ["tests/page-objects"],

  test_workers: false,

  selenium: {
    start_process: false,

    cli_args: {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver": chromedriver.path,
    },
  },

  webdriver: {
    start_process: false,
  },

  test_settings: {
    default: {
      selenium_port: 4444,
      selenium_host: "chrome",

      screenshots: {
        enabled: true,
        path: "tests_output/",
        on_failure: true,
      },

      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: "chrome",
        chromeOptions: {
          w3c: false,
          args: ["--no-sandbox"],
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

- My page object **loginPage.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  url: `http://frontend:8090/login`,
  elements: {
    logoutBt: "#logoutBt",
    loginBt: "#loginBt",
    emailField: 'input[name = "email"]',
    passField: 'input[name = "password"]',
    submitBt: 'button[name = "submit"]',
  },
  commands: [
    {
      fillUpData(selector, data) {
        return this.setValue(selector, data);
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

- The test that is running **loginTest.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  login(browser) {
    const page = browser.page.loginPage();
    const email = "coolEmail@gmail.com";
    const pass = "coolPass";
    page
      .navigate()
      .click("@loginBt")
      .fillUpData("@emailField", email)
      .fillUpData("@passField", pass)
      .click("@submitBt")
      .assert.urlContains("/cards");
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first error is:

```
NoSuchElementError: An error occurred while running .click() command on <Element [name=@logoutBt]>: Timed out while waiting for element "#logoutBt" with "css selector" to be present for 5000 milliseconds.
```

which indicates that *`NoSuchElementError`* was raised while searching for the **Logout** button.

However as per the test steps within **loginTest.js**, ideally you are not supposed to find the **Logout** button just after navigating to the page:

```
.navigate()
.click("@logoutBt")
```

You can find the **Logout** button only after logging in.

---

### Solution

Ideally, the sequence of the commands will be:

```
page
  .navigate()
  .click("@loginBt")
  .fillUpData("@emailField", email)
  .fillUpData("@passField", pass)
  .click("@submitBt")
  .assert.urlContains("/cards");
  .click("@logoutBt")
```

Comment: Hello, I seem to have overlooked it when writing the question, I edited it now. Sadly that is not the issue in this case.

Comment: Your error still have _`Timed out while waiting for element "#logoutBt"`_ which doesn't matches your current code. Possibly you are still overlooking something.

Comment: You are right, I had not merged the branch with the updated tests. However, I am still getting the same stacktrace, I have updated it in the question.
```

Comment: I can still see **edited 59 mins ago**, are you sure you have updated this very question?

Comment: Yes, you can see the new stack trace on the top of the question.